# Improving Default Policy(Rollout Policy) in Mont Carlo Tree Search

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, artificial-intelligence, montecarlo

I've written the MCTS AI in python and now, I'm trying to improve upon its first iteration. I've been told that I need to improve my rollout function. The purpose of the AI is to play the game of dots and boxes.

Right now, after receiving the state of the game, the rollout just plays out the remaining of the game randomely.

Rollout:

```
    while not state.is_terminal:
        state.apply_move(choice(state.legal_moves))
```

I was wondering how can I improve the AI by altering the rollout function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dots an boxes random play is probably pretty poor because it will (1) miss opportunities to fill boxes and (2) give opportunities for opponents to fill boxes, both of which make the playouts less like real play.

So, the simplest change would be to order the moves in the playout. First, take a random move that fills a box, if possible. Second, take a random move that doesn't give the opponent a chance to fill a box. Finally, give the opponent an opportunity to fill a box. (But, here you might want to select a move that gives the opponent the smallest region to fill with high probability.)